# entering mobile number in fixed format in php form

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have small form in php with one input field for mobile number. currently i am entering mobile number in way that it start with 09 and maximum 11 digit . currently i can entered phone number of total 11 digit and if i wrote less than 11 than it successfully show error message. But i want mobile number should be entered in a way that there should b - after first four digit. and rest come after that. for example 0900-12345678  below is my code

```
<form action="action.php">
<label>Mobile No</label>
<input type="text" id="mobno" name="mobno" pattern="09[0-9]{9}" maxlength="11"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Note that client-side validations like this are a _user convenience_. You _must_ also validate the data server-side for security and data integrity.

Comment: So you knew how to write literal characters, a character class and a numeric quantifier, but you didn't know how to add a hyphen to the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're using enforces a mobile number starting with "09" and followed by exactly 9 digits. However, this doesn't match the format you want (e.g., 0300-12345678), and it doesn't allow for the inclusion of a - after the first four digits

You need to use this pattern instead **03[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{8}**

- **03**: Specifies that the mobile number should start with "03".
- **[0-9]{2}**: Matches exactly two digits after "03".
- **"-"**: Requires a hyphen after the first four digits.
- **[0-9]{8}**: Matches exactly eight digits after the hyphen.

And you should increase the maxlenght to **13**

```html
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <label for="mobno">Mobile No</label>
    <input type="text" id="mobno" name="mobno" pattern="03[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{8}" maxlength="13" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think change your pattern to this:

```
<input type="text" id="mobno" name="mobno" pattern="03[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{8}" maxlength="13" required>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.